# Does "leading on" have a sexual connotation?

Tags: connotation

In the first consultant session with someone of the opposite sex, where we explored a specific subset of her business challenges, a potential solution came to my mind. I did, however, not mention that solution, because in this stage I wanted to get a good image of the status quo without biasing her.

In the speaking notes, can I say: "I did not mention that solution because I did not want to lead her on", or would that have a sexual connotation, which would be inappropriate? Is it professional to phrase it like this?

Comment: The answer depends too much on the nature of your "sessions", the nature of the work, who is overseeing the work, etc.

Comment: You might prefer _prompt her_ or _influence her_. Or say _I wanted her to find a solution independently_.

Comment: Write it as an answer @BoldBen. "Bias" may also work.

Answer (score 1):

The weight of dictionary definition says that you are not necessarily being sexual. Here are three examples:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead-on)
> *to persuade someone to believe something that is untrue*

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lead-on)
> *If someone leads you on, they encourage you to do something, especially by pretending that something is true*
> and also
> *to lure or entice, especially into trouble or wrongdoing*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20on)
> *to entice or induce to adopt or continue in a course or belief especially when unwise or mistaken*

Some of these definitions (such as *lure* and *entice*) are consistent with sexual overtures, although not necessarily so and not restricted to that usage.

However, think of the synonyms. Here for example is the M-W list:
*allure, bait, beguile, betray, decoy, entice, lure, seduce, solicit, tempt*

Many of these are heading strongly towards being implicitly sexual (*allure, solicit, seduce, tempt*)

I therefore suggest that context is all-important. You may use *lead on* if you make very clear that the leading on related only to a line of argument.